# How do I return a String in a try/catch statment?

Tags: java

I am trying to return a String from the following method.

```
public String openCon() {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        URL sitex = new URL("http://" + scan.nextLine());
        URLConnection connection = sitex.openConnection();
        Object content = sitex.getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sitex.openStream()));
        String str;
        String x = "1";
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
          x += str;
        }
        in.close();
        return x;

   }
   catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem isn't returning from the `try` block - the problem is that you *aren't* returning anything if an exception is thrown. You're catching the exception... but then reaching the end of the method without returning anything. (To put it in more technical terminology: the end of a non-void method should not be reachable.)

Personally, I would just remove the `catch` block entirely, and add `throws` declarations for any exceptions which are thrown within the body. You're not really *handling* the exceptions - you're just printing them out and ignoring them, which is very rarely a good idea. Catching `Exception` is usually a pretty bad idea to start with.

As an aside, you should *also* close your `BufferedReader` and `URLConnection` values in a `finally` block so they're closed even in the case of an exception. I'd also suggest either passing a fixed encoding name to `InputStreamReader`, or using a higher-level HTTP client API which will use the content-type header from the response. Oh, and use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation in a loop.

Comment: You are leaving the rest of us not much to comment on :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not initialise the variable before the `try` statement, and place the return statement after it?

Answer (score 1):

If there's an exception before the return statement, the method won't return anything.  Since you're not really handling the exception, I recommend you just let it bubble up and handle it at a higher level.  This may be the main method if there's no better place.  You will need to declare the method as `throws IOException` and possibly add other exception classes.

Also, use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure your instances (`BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`) are closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should return something in the catch block, for example:

```
   catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return "";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String result = ""
try{
   result = "OK";
}catch (Exception e){
   result = e.toString();
}finally{
   return result;
}
```